# Using Filter() to skip a form element

Tags: jquery

So I have a form with 3 fields name="one", name="two" and name="three"

I am doing this to select all fields **except** the one with name=three:

```
$this.filter(function () {
     return !({ "three"})[this.name];
});
```

Not sure how to do it. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like,

```
$('#yourForm').find('*').filter(':not([name="three"])')
```

or as @arkascha suggested you can use,

```
$('#yourForm').find(':not([name="three"])')
```

Comment: What is the empty `find('*')` required for? Why doesn't `$('#yourForm').find(':not([name="three"])')` work?

Comment: Can you explain why do I need to use find() here? Also I want to use an anony function inside filter()

Comment: @arkascha Yes, that's right, I just answered as the OP is expecting an answer which uses .filter() :)

Comment: @Thomasmkov We are using a `.find()` here, because we are going to select all the descendants of that form. `.find()` will help us to select the descendants as per the selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#yourForm').find(':not([name="three"])')
```

---

```
$('#yourForm').find('*').filter(':not([name="three"])')
```

Comment: I want to use filter(). Any disadvantage in using filter?